# Understanding Transactions

Tags: transactions

I am trying to understand all the properties of the transaction object. On the developers site (https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/docs/communication-model) they provide the below transaction object:

`{
  "expiration": "2018-04-01T15:20:44",
  "region": 0,
  "ref_block_num": 42580,
  "ref_block_prefix": 3987474256,
  "net_usage_words": 21,
  "kcpu_usage": 1000,
  "delay_sec": 0,
  "context_free_actions": [],
  "actions": [{
      "account": "eosio.token",
      "name": "issue",
      "authorization": [{
          "actor": "eosio",
          "permission": "active"
        }
      ],
      "data": "00000000007015d640420f000000000004454f5300000000046d656d6f"
    }
  ],
  "signatures": [
    ""
  ],
  "context_free_data": []
}`

My **questions** are 1) what context_free_actions is? 2)where are the scope and recipients fields that dan pointed out in this https://steemit.com/eos/@dan/eos-developer-s-log-stardate-201707-9 article? Scope was used so as a block can produced parallel? 3)How this achieved without the scope property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Context free actions don't depend on
   (can't read or modify) the state of the blockchain and can therefore
   be executed in parallel.
2. Receivers are notified and can "discard" a transaction if they deploy a custom dispatcher (see eosio::on_notify())
3. Scope is already implemented in the state, each table has a scope - but it's not used for multi-threading yet.

Comment: about the receivers statement. How does the node for which account to run the apply() method if its not in the trx?

Comment: The trx-example you provided above is the scheme of a typical "issue"-transaction and while issuing a token there are no additional accounts and therefore no receivers involved. To notify a receiver you would add require_recipient(receiver) to your smart contract.

Comment: Ok so an additional field would be added to the trx object in that case.How this field would called? recipients or receivers? thank you

Comment: you don't neccessary need to add it to the transaction. If you for example automatically send rewards to holders of a specific token every night and just call a single action for that which does the rest for hundrets of accounts, depending on your implementation you don't have to add the receipients to the action-parameters. All you need is to call require_receipient([valid_eos_account_name]) from within your contract.

Comment: I know the implementation side, I am programming eos smart contracts for like 1 year before now. I am just asking for a paper I am writing about Eos and so as to clarify the fields :)